# Adding SCNLight to SCNNode turns SCNNode black

Tags: swift, scenekit

I'm trying to add `SCNLight` to a `SCNSphere` (`SCNNode`) in `SceneKit`. It works amazing, the only problem is that the source sphere to which the `SCNLight` is attached is completely black, because being the source, it doesn't get any light at all. How do I make sure the source (i.e. that Sphere) is completely lit?

Here's the light source code:

```swift
public func addLightSource(position: SCNVector3) -> SCNLight {
        let light = SCNLight()
        light.type = .omni
        light.intensity = 5000
        light.temperature = CGFloat(3500)
        return light
}
```

and later

```swift
ParentNode.light = addLightSource(position: absolutePosition)
```

which works but turns `ParentNode` black.

Comment: Adjust the light bit mask.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a [categoryBitMask](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/1407994-categorybitmask) instance property for sphere and for light to exclude/include ones:

```
func addLightSource(position: SCNVector3) -> SCNLight {
    let light = SCNLight()
    light.type = .omni
    light.intensity = 5000
    light.categoryBitMask = 1
    light.temperature = CGFloat(2000)
    return light
}

let sphereNode1 = SCNNode()
sphereNode1.geometry = SCNSphere(radius: 2)
sphereNode1.position = SCNVector3(x: 10, y: 0, z: 0)
sphereNode1.light = addLightSource(position: sphereNode1.position)
sphereNode1.categoryBitMask = 1
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(sphereNode1)
```